# Boot console overscan on HiDPI

Tags: boot, console, resolution

I have a HiDPI screen: the boot console has the native resolution, so it's extremely tiny, almost unreadable. I can "zoom" it by passing (in my case) `video=1280x800` BUT there is an overscan I can't get rid of. Passing `video=1280x800m` rather than `video=1280x800,margin_bottom=<a value in pixels>` doesn't change absolutely anything.
Is there an effective way to get rid of the overscan?

Comment: Sure.  Stop treating HDMI like it was suitable for computer displays.  Use as an interface something that doesn't think it's talking to a television.  Failing that, hopefully whatever you're using as a monitor as a switch to turn off overscan.  The computer isn't doing it.

Comment: I don't use HDMI at all